# Is there a way to set the console's cursor left position to a minimum value?

Tags: c#, console

I am throwing an application to help with some workflow, and I am reusing an old library I wrote a while ago that works perfectly for what I need. However, I am looking to do some more stylistic changes such as setting the console's cursor position to a minimum left value, so each newline is indented.

My reason for this is because my library controls the output, and unfortunately, refactoring it to return the output for manual writing is further difficult, still.

I essentially have a class that does some work, and then displays some results to the screen. These results I simply want to indent several characters.

Is there a means to do this? I know typically you would manually control the cursor position, but since I don't control how the output occurs, I have no means to do so.

Comment: I doubt this can be done. You might have to rethink your problem.

Comment: Could you use pipes? I mean, read output of your legacy tool and process it line by line indenting text.

Comment: @Maximus Sounds like an interesting concept. I've never heard of that. Any resources?

Comment: MSDN? ;) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: It would not work if you application requires real console buffers and does not support redirections.